# How to get all the woocommerce orders billing or shipping email using php array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column',11);
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
$reordered_columns = array();

    // Woocommerce version 3.3+ compatibility
    $location_after = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.3', '<' ) ? 'order_notes' : 'order_status';

    // Inserting the new column in a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key == $location_after ){
            $reordered_columns['pvdl']= __('PVF/DL', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
if('pvdl' == $column){
        //echo 'Working on it';
        $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
        $email = $order->get_billing_email();
        //var_dump($email);
        mailchecker($email);

    }

}
function mailchecker($test_mail){
    
    $life = array();
    array_push($life, $test_mail);
    var_dump($life);
}
```

I was trying to push the emails to an empty array but it only shows the current order email. I know I am doing something dumb here but I am stuck. Any kind soul wanna help me with this?

Comment: What is your actual purpose ? To show billing or shipping email in the newly added order post column ?

Comment: sorry about late reply. so what I want is to get all the guest and user email address from orders and push them to an array.

Comment: So I am trying to show, how many time an email was sent, asking payment verification per order. And then show the count number on order list column. Let me know if you have a better idea. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try this:

```
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 3 ); // change accordingly
function custom_orders_list_column_content()
{
    $billing_email = $skip_duplicate = array();

    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' =>'wc-completed', // change accordingly
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    ) );
    
    foreach( $customer_orders as $order){

        $order_id = $order->ID;

        if($order_id){

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            $bemail  = $order->get_billing_email();
            
            if(!in_array($bemail, $skip_duplicate)){
                $billing_email[] = $bemail;
                array_push($skip_duplicate,$bemail);
            }
            
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($billing_email); exit;
}
```

You can change "post_status" and "add_action" events accordingly.

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot. This is what I needed and now I can start working on the orders. Huge help :)

Comment: Thanks, brother, I am happy to help you